# Class 'Illuminate\Support\Collection' not found in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, router, fatal-error

> FatalErrorException in Router.php line 737:
>   Class 'Illuminate\Support\Collection' not found

Getting this error while uploading on hosting server. I have updated my composer but am still getting this error.

Comment: What laravel version, and can you post your router file?

Comment: Try running `composer dump-autoload`? Also check your `composer.json` file -- it may be pointing to the wrong vendor file.

Answer (score 1):

Just change php version to a matching version.